# How do I get text of nested div in a specific HTML list element as alert message onclick

Tags: javascript

This is my HTML file structure:

```js
var li = document.getElementById("myList").getElementsByTagName("li");
for (var i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    li.onclick = function () {
        alert(document.getElementsByClassName("title")[i].innerHTML);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="maincontent">
    <ul id="myList">
        <li>
            <div class="image">
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/">
                <div class="button option-vertical-grid"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="info">
                <div class="url">lorempixel.com</div>
                <div class="title" id="title">M1</div>
                <div class="play"><section>0</section></div>
            </div>
            <div class="info2">
                <div class="date">30.11.2016</div>
                <div class="button option-vertical"></div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="image">
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/102/100/">
                <div class="button option-vertical-grid"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="info">
                <div class="url">lorempixel.com</div>
                <div class="title">M2</div>
                <div class="play"><section>0</section></div>
            </div>
            <div class="info2">
                <div class="date">30.11.2016</div>
                <div class="button option-vertical"></div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="image">
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/103/100/">
                <div class="button option-vertical-grid"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="info">
                <div class="url">lorempixel.com</div>
                <div class="title">M3</div>
                <div class="play"><section>0</section></div>
            </div>
            <div class="info2">
                <div class="date">30.11.2016</div>
                <div class="button option-vertical"></div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**The first task is:**
On click of the list it should show an alert message with the title of the clicked list, i.e. the text in the div class "title", i.e. (M1 or M2....)

**The second task is:**
On click of the div class "button option-vertical" it should give me another alert containing the class title as in task above and additionally the img src value from the div class "image", for example: (http://lorempixel.com/100/100)

When showing the alert from the second task, the alert from the first task should not be shown and vice versa. Please all without jQuery, only JavaScript.

With the JavaScript I tried above, a click on the list item doesn't give me any alert message.

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before attempting to ask more questions. This is basically a requirements dump with some code snippet that is incomplete and does not really try and solve the requirements, *doesn't work* is also useless, because it also *doesn't actually try and do what you want*.

Comment: Please read [Why is “Doesn't work, can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) before attempting to ask more questions.

Comment: It doesn't work refers to the tasks I explained above. But thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: yeah *doesn't work* is useless unless you detail *how does it not work* otherwise there is no *problem statement*. **The relevant close reason:** *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, **a specific problem or error** and the **shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)*. You are missing the last two making this a requirements dump.

Comment: In addition to the issue mentioned in both answers, you are also experiencing a duplicate of [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/750486)

Answer (score 0):

> The `getElementsByClassName()|getElementsByTagName` method returns a collection of all elements in the document with the specified class|tag name, as a NodeList object.
>   The NodeList object represents a collection of nodes. The nodes can be accessed by index numbers. The index starts at 0.

```
var li = document.getElementById("myList").getElementsByTagName("li"),
    len = li.length,
    i;
for (i = 0; i < len; i += 1) {
    li[i].onclick = function() {
        //Li only has one child with class "title"
        alert(this.getElementsByClassName("title")[0].innerHTML);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi avril, maybe something is missing, I get no alert message with your code.

Comment: @Schopenhauer [see](https://jsfiddle.net/tsxry7n9/)

Comment: Thanks...I got it!